# Does Linux get_user_pages guarantee pages will not be swapped?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, dma

Suppose I called `get_user_pages` on a buffer from user space. I know that this will essentially "fault" all the pages to make sure they are present in RAM.

However, does this guarantee that they will stay in RAM and not get swapped out?

Here's a quick example of some code I tried on a 4.19.69 kernel:

```
down_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
rc = get_user_pages(
    start,          //start virtual address
    1,              //number of pages
    FOLL_WRITE,     //flags, see FOLL_* in mm.h
    &p,             //destination page* array
    NULL            //destination vma* array (unneeded)
);
up_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);

if (rc <= 0) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "Could not get user page :(\n");
    return rc;
}

printk(KERN_INFO "Page is %sreserved\n", PageReserved(p) ? "" : "not ");
```

As per the `dmesg` messages, the page is not marked as reserved. Suppose I started a DMA transfer to/from this (physical) page. Does this mean that Linux might swap it out to disk while the DMA hardware is running? If so, what is the correct way to guarantee that the page stays put?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[get_user_pages()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/mm/gup.c#L1607) has a [comment](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/mm/gup.c#L1600) referring to [get_user_pages_remote()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/mm/gup.c#L1149). The latter's doc [says](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/mm/gup.c#L1093):

> get_user_pages_remote() - pin user pages in memory

So they won't get swapped until you unpin them with e.g. [put_user_pages()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/mm/gup.c#L108).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know how get_user_pages_remote guarantees the page won't be swapped? Maybe it sets a flag in the struct page?

Comment: AFAICT `struct page` represents a page of physical memory, hence as long as the struct exists (i.e. has a reference), it points to memory, not swap. There are `PG_reserved` and `PG_locked` but they aren't about swapping.

Comment: @MarcoMerlini The page frame reclamation would check page->_refcount to see if there are extra references on the page. See is_page_cache_freeable() for v5.7 kernel.